# Laravel - Undefined variable: request

Tags: laravel, get-request, undefined-variable

My http://localhost:8888/VGL/public/category/18?sty=3

When `dd($request->sty);` equal 3

however I put `$request->sty` in the `whereHas` is

> Undefined variable: request

```
public function show(Request $request, $id)
{
    $products = Product::with('features')
        ->whereHas('features', function ($q) {
            return $q->where('id', $request->sty);
        })
        ->where('category_id',17)
        ->get();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

If you want to use any variable inside the `where closure` then you have to pass that variable inside the `use($variable)`

```
public function show(Request $request, $id)
{
    $products = Product::with('features')
        ->whereHas('features', function ($q) use($request) {
            return $q->where('id', $request->sty);
        })
        ->where('category_id',17)
        ->get();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I forget to inject into the query function

Comment: Glad to help you.  you can Accept as the answer if you want. so other developers find answer easily